# Controller method not found when using route parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm trying to build a application that forces users to confirm their email adreses when they sign up. I send a email, containing a link like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/verifieren/TOKEN&user=USERNAME
```

Now, when I try to visit this link, the following error pops up on my screen:

```
NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 91:
Controller method not found.
```

From the stack trace, I got the following

```
at Controller->missingMethod(array('verifieren', 'GILDE-jOWPBRhcOW1fUFg77xnb0kgM22CUm4&user=Wesley'))
```

What I think it means is that it tries to call `verifieren` as a method?

This is the route I'm using:

```
Route::get('/verifieren/{{ confirmation_code }}&user={{ username }}', 'Authentication\AuthenticationController@mailConformation');
```

And that route corresponds to the following method:

```
public function mailConfirmation($code, $username) {
        $user = User::where(["confirmation_code" => $code, "username" => $username])->first();

        $user->active = '1';
        $user->confirmation_code = null;
        $user->active_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $user->save();

        return redirect('/welkom')->with("flash_notice", "account_succesfully_activated");
}
```

I have absolutely no idea why this would happen. I thought it could be other routes interfering, but it turns out it wasn't that.

For me, this is quite new stuff, so I can imagine that I made a rookie error in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is spelling mistake of method name in route and controller method name

In you route you have method name as

```
@mailConformation
```

But in your Controller your method name is

```
mailConfirmation($code,$username)
```

So, Correct your spelling of the method name in the route as :

```
Route::get('/verifieren/{{ confirmation_code }}&user={{ username }}', 'Authentication\AuthenticationController@mailConfirmation');
```

Comment: The fact that I didnt spot that makes me sad, thanks!

Comment: @WesleyPeeters yeah happens sometimes .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
http://localhost:8000/verifieren/TOKEN&user=USERNAME
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000/verifieren/TOKEN?user=USERNAME
```

You are suing & instead of ?

and moreover the method name in your route is "mailConformation" and your method name in your controller is "mailConfirmation"

change

```
'Authentication\AuthenticationController@mailConformation'
```

to

```
'Authentication\AuthenticationController@mailConfirmation'
```

in your route